# SAP RFC server with Python, is it possible?

Tags: python, saprfc, pyrfc

I have a service that can make SAP RFC requests to some server. Assume that I can not modify this service, but need to handle such requests and process their data.
So I want to develop my own server that will process RFC requests, I prefer Python but can do it with C++ too.

I read that it should be possible to do with PyRFC
https://sap.github.io/PyRFC/server.html#server-server

but there are "gateway parameters" and I don't know what I should use here, and in my concept I do not need SAP Gateway here, I just want to process requests in my standalone server.

Is it possible to develop own standalone server for processing RFC requests with Pyhton or C++?
Or it can be used only with SAP Gateway? In this case what I need to do in SAP Gateway side?

Comment: From reading the docs, I don't think those parameters are required.  Unfortunately, I know nothing about PyRFC or SAP, but it definitely looks like you can create a standalone server.

Comment: So to clarify - you want to have some 3rd party non-SAP product issue RFC calls to your server instead of an SAP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a SAP Gateway server/service anyway - and by that, I don't mean the SAP Gateway product that is used to provide OData services, but the `sapgw` process that is part of the SAP NetWeaver Application Server ABAP installation. This process is required because your custom RFC server registers itself at a `sapgw` server (specifying an identifier in the process), and the `sapgw` instance will route outgoing (!) calls to your implementation based on the identifier that is specified in the RFC destination as well.

As for direct communication between non-SAP systems (so non-outgoing RFC calls) - that should be possible as well, but I strongly believe that the calling service will have to be adapted to the fact that it's not talking to a "real" ABAP back-end. You'll also have to mock the DDIC Repository access, the user authentication process, ... - realistically speaking, it might be easier to simply install an ABAP system and do the processing there.